# HTML5 video support Windows Phone mail client

Tags: windows-phone-7, email, windows-phone-8, html5-video

We are trying to supply video in emails and it will fall back to a static image if html5 video is not supported. We are having issues with Windows Phones mail client in that it appears to support HTML video because it loads the player. You can see the play icon in the middle but it does not play. It is totally unresponsive.

Does anyone know if there is a specific format videos need to be supplied in? Or if it is just an incompletely finished feature? It is worth noting I am testing this on WP7, not WP8 as I don't currently have access to that device.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use H264 codec for your video with MP4 format.

This link can help you : [HTML5 support in IE9 mobile](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/10/13/html5-video-support-in-ie9-mobile.aspx).

To do this, you can use ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i you_video_file.[avi/mp4/mkv] -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```